# Should Javascript files include the BOM or not?

Tags: javascript, web-standards, byte-order-mark

I believe that most people suggest using UTF-8 as the encoding for Javascript files.

Is there a standard about whether those files include the *Byte-Order Mark*, or do not included it? (i.e. Should JS files be served with/without the UTF-8 BOM?)

I'd like to see an RFC, or a "de facto" standard of this, and not so much an opinion of which is preferred by individuals.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926

An answer that is unspecific to JS, but might be relevant.

Comment: A related issue, here, where browsers are confused about the encoding of a javascript resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102142/why-must-i-specify-charset-attributes-for-by-script-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia has a good explanation of why NOT to include a BOM with UT8.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#cite_note-3

"Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8, but may be encountered in contexts where UTF-8 data is converted from other encoding forms that use a BOM or where the BOM is used as a UTF-8 signature"

Comment: @jon-sykes should get credit for referencing a similar question, and the authoritative source more directly, but I am marking this as the accepted answer, since it includes the same info.