# How can I run a javascript code using a python web server?

Tags: javascript, python, server

I have used BaseHTTPRequestHandler to create the server. I can run a normal html file without any problem but when I try to call a js program using

```
<script type="application/javascript";charset="utf8", src="prueba.js">  </script>
```

in my html file it doesn't work.
My file prueba.js is just a line containing console.log('hello');. When I execute my server starts running but it prints anything instead of 'Hello' in the browser console.

I have already tried to change the MIME type from text/html to text/javascript and application/javascript and nothing changed.

Comment: And where's the file located? As in, what's the directory structure?

Comment: Look in the browser's developer tools' network tab. Does it download the correct file with the correct contents?

Answer (score 1):

The markup is incorrectly formatted. When browsers encounter incorrect syntax, they have various strategies to recover. In the case of Chrome (which I'm using), eliminating the comma between attributes allowed a test script to load. But you should also replace the semicolon with a space.

```
<script type="application/javascript" charset="utf8" src="prueba.js"></script>
```

The correct `type` attribute [is `text/javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195504/684776) if you're using HTML4.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="prueba.js"></script>
```

The attribute is optional if you're using HTML5.

```
<script charset="utf8" src="prueba.js"></script>
```

And you [can omit the `charset` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106781/684776) if its value matches the encoding of your HTML document.

```
<script src="prueba.js"></script>
```

Comment: While true, not *sure* it would cause this problem. Depends on how the parser treats garbage between attributes.

Comment: Fair. I just ran a quick test w/ Chrome. I'll add an explanation.